# where to get all sets of view items in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

In my Xcode when I create view items like buttons, text fields, etc.,  I see only very limited list of items (like only 2 kinds of button..). But I saw that Xcode has different buttons: round button, rectangle button, gradient button, and many others. Why don't I see them in my Xcode list of view items? How would I get the whole set to design my app?
Thank you

[image]

Comment: Those buttons are OS X buttons, not iOS buttons.

Comment: @duci9y how would I get iOS buttons? I am developing iPhone app...

Comment: The buttons in your screenshot are iOS buttons. Rounded button, rectangle button, gradient button, etc, are OS X buttons.

Comment: oh, is there any way to get different kinds of nice buttons for iOS?

Comment: I'd say you create them. Also, please become familiar with an iOS device before you start developing for it.

Comment: Also have a look at http://cocoacontrols.com